# c++ function returns nan instead of double

Tags: c++, scanf, nan, cin

SOLVED "missed the return after the loop after a correct value was entered"

I use scanf_s to get input from the console. I wrote a function that checks the input and if it's wrong it requests to input again.

If i input a correct value the first time everything is fine. If i have to enter the value a second time inside the funktion everything is fine but insted of returning this value the funtion returns NaN. Why is the double value lost in return only if i use scanf_s twice?

If i call input and enter a correct value a double is returned. If i enter a value less or equal 0 i have to enter the value again but this time NaN is returned. While debugging i can see that eingabe is still a double.

```
double input() {
    int n = -1;
    double eingabe = 0.0;

    scanf_s("%lf", &eingabe);

    clearBuffer();
    if (eingabe <= 0.0)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Invald input");
            printf("Try again: ");

            n = scanf_s("%lf", eingabe);
            clearBuffer();
        } while (eingabe <= 0.0);
    }
    else
    {
        return eingabe;
    }
}

void clearBuffer() {
    //alles aus dem Buffer lesen bis man bei EOF (END OF FILE) ankommt
    int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
            if (c == '\n')
                break;
        }
}
```

Comment: If you are compiling as C++, why not use `std::cin` instead of `scanf_s`, and `std::cout` instead of `printf`?

Comment: What did your debugger tell you was going on?  Did you see it hit your return statement as expected?

Comment: Follow up - did your compiler give you any warnings about your input() function?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the return value of `scanf_s`? I/O means interacting with the environment, *which you do not control*, so you must always check everything.

Comment: Your second call to `scanf_s` uses `eingabe` rather than `&eingabe`! While there are some good answers to your code as a whole, this is probably why NaN is returned except for first attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return the value inside `if (eingabe <= 0.0)`.

You have to rewirite your code, so the eingabe will always be returned.

Like so:

```
if (eingabe <= 0.0)
{
    do
    {
        printf("Invald input");
        printf("Try again: ");

        n = scanf_s("%lf", &eingabe);
        clearBuffer();
    } while (eingabe <= 0.0);
}
return eingabe;
```

Or like so:

```
if (eingabe <= 0.0)
{
    do
    {
        printf("Invald input");
        printf("Try again: ");

        n = scanf_s("%lf", &eingabe);
        clearBuffer();
    } while (eingabe <= 0.0);
    return eingabe;
}
else
{
    return eingabe;
}
```

In my opinion, first case is better.

**edit**

Here I made some refactoring with your code. Not everyone will like it, because of `while(true)` stuff and `continue` and `return` not in the end of a function. But at least it is written in C++ and from my opinion it is pretty natural and reads clearly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

double input() {
    double eingabe;

    while (true) {
        std::cout << "Enter a positive real number: ";
        std::cin >> eingabe;

        if (std::cin.fail()) {
            std::cout << "Number expected." << std::endl;
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }

        if (eingabe <= 0) {
            std::cout << "Positive number expected." << std::endl;
            continue;
        }

        return eingabe;
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus, `if(x) do { ... } while (x)` is equivalent to `while (x) { ... }` and much more readable.

Comment: and since we dont do anything with the `n` we could just delete it

Comment: In summary - the reason for the bug is because the rule of "don't repeat yourself" has been violated, and a mistake was made while repeating.

Comment: @Exagon or best, check the return values of environment-related I/O functions... or even best, use C++ `std::cin` in lieu of `::scanf_s()`.

Comment: @YSC, guys, yes, but it is more like [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question. The code should be written in C++, since this is C++. Using std::cin and std::cout. And so on...

Comment: @vasi1y This is not a critique on your answer, whose (which?) I upvoted. Just needed to get it out. This type of code hurts. And we know its not yours.

Comment: @vasi1y you are right i simply missed the return after the loop after a correct value was entered. THANKS MAN i was so blind..... I guess from now on "single return" it is :)

Comment: Note that `scanf_s` together with format specifier `"%lf"` has the same effect as `scanf` and is to no extend more "secure".

Comment: @YSC made some improvements. Hope no one gets hurt.

Answer (score 0):

I think there some issues to be discussed in your solution.

First, not all control paths return a value, which probably lead to undesired results of function `input`; your compiler should have warned you.

Second, your error condition is based on the double value a user enters in the sense that negative numbers or `0` are treated as error. If you ever want to input also negative numbers or 0, then this approach will have to be reworked. You should use the return value of `scanf`, which can indicate if the format specified has been read successfully.

Third, you use `scanf_s`, i.e. the "secure" version of `scanf` in the sense that `scanf_s` could limit the characters written to a buffer; This does not make sense here for two reasons: (a) you do not provide a limit for the buffer as additional argument, and (b) scanning `%lf` is limited by data type `double` anyway. Confer, for example, `scanf_s`-reference on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx):

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size
>   to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string
>   control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable

Fourth, the construct is probably a little bit to complicated, as, for example, statements `double eingabe = 0.0` followed by `if (eingabe <= 0.0)` does not make to much sense.

So let me propose a "shorter" solution for function `input`:

```
double input() {

    double eingabe = 0.0;
    int validInput = 0;
    do {
        if (scanf("%lf", &eingabe) == 1 && eingabe > 0)
            validInput = 1;
        else {
          printf("Invald input\n"
                "Try again:");
          scanf("%*[^\n]\n");
        }
    }
    while (!validInput);
    return eingabe;
}
```

Note that statement `scanf("%*[^\n]\n")` consumes any character until the next `\n` including the `\n` without writing it to any buffer (expressed by `*` in the format).